# Should classes have foreign keys in variables when persisting a model in SQLite?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm persisting the save-games of a game with a little model of 4 classes. I have two crossed relationships between two classes. It is very simple when I was not using SQLite, but now, I'm having problems to adapt my game to persist in SQLite for that issue.

Imagine for example two classes: `Person` and `Car`. A `Person` can have n `Cars`, so it is a 1-n relationship, with the `Foreign Key` of `Person` (`Person.id`) stored in a column of `Cars` table. That is simple, but also a `Person` have it's `Favourite Car`, which is by default the first `Car`. That relationship must be represented by a column in `Person` which is a Foreign Key to `Car.id`.

Now, when I'm inserting a `Person`, I need to insert the list of `Cars`, so I need to iterate through my `Car` list and do an `Insert` of each `Car` passing the `Person.id` `primary key` to save it as a `Foreign Key` on each `Car`.

But then, I have an issue, because I also need to store in `Person` the `Favourite Car` (by default the first), which is a `Car` instance variable in my `Person` object. At this point, I need that `Car` `Car.id` column to store it in the `Person` column which represents the `Foreign Key` `Car.id` for the `Favourite Car`. So I need to do an `update table` of the recently created `Person` to store that `Car.id`. It is a crazy behaviour which I can't feel comfortable of. And also, each time I update something in `Person` and `Car`, this can get more complicated, because each update will need to do all that previous job again.

I think that a way to do this with less complexity would be to store the `Car.id` of the `Favourite Car` in each `Person` Java/Kotlin object instead of storing the instance of the `Car`. And each time the app needs to get the instance, ask for it to the database using that `Car.id`. I don't like it, but it seems to make less complex to persist the data in SQLite.

How can I achieve this in a simple way?

Comment: A column `Favourite` in the table `Car` with values 0 or 1 would make more sense.

Comment: what are you using to save entities to db? spring data? hibernate? jdbc api?

Comment: @forpas well, I reduced my code to that simple thing, the app is not about persons and cars, I reduced my problem to that simple example, and there is not only a favourite column, you can select a "car" as favourite but you also can select 4 or 5 cars more for other things inside person. So doing a column in Car is still a better option for you? You can change "favourite car" with "current car". Whould current car be a column in cars also? I can't see it

Comment: @Nebra no complex SDK, I'm doing vanilla with SqliteOpenHelper in android: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite Just codifying every query and every table.

Comment: It seems that you reduced the requirement too much in your question. I proposed a column in the table Cars based on what I read. If the requirement is different then you must explain it better. A 3d table, that links the other 2 could be another option.

Comment: @forpas imagine "favourite car" "current car" and "worst car" variables in Person. I don't understand what you mean with creating a third table for specifying these variables in the sqlite. Can you explain yourself how to do that please?

Comment: Imagine a table "Properties" with columns "id" and "property" and rows like: (1, 'favourite'), (2, 'current'), (3, 'worst'), ... A column "property_id" in the table "Cars" having values 1, 2, 3, ... referencing the "id" in Properties.

Comment: @forpas thank you, I will think on it, but for now I think that it will make it even more complex. For example, each time I change a favourite or a current car, I need to update first the car that was previously that property, and then update the car that is that property now. I'm not sure if this is a better option, but maybe if I try i whould see it with better eyes. Do you think that I need to avoid crossed relationships like the explained in my question every time I can avoid them? even creating new tables like yours?

Comment: *Do you think that I need to avoid crossed relationships...?* yes. In any case you may also need triggers, if you don't plan to take care of updates and deletions in your app's code. Crossed relationships are real trouble when triggers are involved.